# Regex to add extension in specific lines

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to add a new path with the name of the last path from import with .cjs extension to every import which contains 'primereact'.

For example:

```
import { nanoid } from "nanoid";
import { Button } from "primereact/button";
```

Should be:

```
import { nanoid } from "nanoid";
import { Button } from "primereact/button/button.cjs";
```

I want to connect regex with js replace function

```
string.replace(//g, '');
```

I have a regex to find the line which contains `import` and `primereact`, but can't add necessary file with extension.

```
.*(import)+.*(primereact)+.*
```

Comment: You need to do that on the server. The import statement will not be changed by script later in the page

Comment: You can also use .htaccess

Comment: Yes, I know.  I want to run the script on build file before serving the app, (Why it's necessaary that's different story)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const source = `import { nanoid } from "nanoid";
import { Button } from "primereact/button";
import { Butter } from "primereact/butter";`
const regex = /(\bimport\b.*?\bfrom +"primereact\/)([^"]+)/g;
let result = source.replace(regex, '$1$2/$2.cjs'); 
console.log(result);
```

Output:

```
import { nanoid } from "nanoid";
import { Button } from "primereact/button/button.cjs";
import { Butter } from "primereact/butter/butter.cjs";
```

Explanation of regex:

- `(\bimport\b.*?\bfrom +"primereact\/)` -- capture group 1 using word boundaries `\b` to avoid false positives
- `([^"]+)` -- capture group 2 capturing everything up to double quote
- the replace composes the desired string from capture groups `$1` and `$2`

Answer (score 1):

the following regex captures the last word in every input line which contains primereact:

```
(?<=(^|\n)import.+?primereact[^\/]*\/).+?(?=\";)
```

the resulting match of your example input would then be: button

using this match, we can add the necessary path information like in this pseudo code:

```
var regex = "(?<=(^|\n)import.+?primereact[^\/]*\/).+?(?=\";)";
foreach (var line in lines)
{
   var match = line.match(regex);
   if (match)
   {
      line = line.replace(regex, match.result + "/" + match.result + ".cjs");
   }
}
```

Comment: Lookbehind is not supported by all browsers, notably Safari

Answer (score 1):

You might use for example a pattern with capture groups, and use those groups in the replacement.

```
^(import\s+{[^{}]*}\s+from\s+(["'])primereact\/)(.*?)\2
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `import\s+` Match import, 1+ whitespace chars
  - `{[^{}]*}` Match from `{...}`
  - `\s+from\s+` Match `from` between whitespace chars
  - `(["'])` Capture either `"` or `'` in **group 2**
  - `primereact\/` Match `primereact/`
- `)` Close group 1
- `(.*?)` Capture **group 3**, match any char, as few as possible
- `\2` Match the same closing quote that was captured in group 2

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nYKCya/1)

```js
const regex = /^(import\s+{[^{}]*}\s+from\s+(["'])primereact\/)(.*?)\2/gm;
const str = `import { nanoid } from "nanoid";
import { Button } from "primereact/button";`;
console.log(str.replace(regex, `$1$3/$3.cjs$2`));
```